# How have famous sequences/numbers often gotten their names from people who ‘discovered’ them?

Tags: soft-question, math-history

How have well-known number sequences often gotten their names from people fundamental to our understanding of them? For instance, how did we come to call the Fibonacci numbers, Pell numbers, and Catalan numbers what we do? How did the people they are named after refer to them, and is there any record of how long after initial discoveries on such numbers that they got their names?

Comment: Maybe one for https://hsm.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 1):

Most often, famous sequences are credited to a mathematician by another mathematician, sometimes erroneously. Quoting wikipedia,

[Fibonacci numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number)
are named after Italian mathematician Leonardo of Pisa, later known as Fibonacci, who introduced the sequence in 1202. The name "Fibonacci sequence" was first used by the 19th-century number theorist Édouard Lucas.
However, the sequence had been described earlier in Indian mathematics. Knowledge of the Fibonacci sequence was expressed as early as Pingala (c. 450 BC–200 BC).

The name of the [Pell numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell_number) stems from Leonhard Euler's mistaken attribution of the equation and the numbers derived from it to John Pell.

The [Catalan sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number) was described in the 18th century by Leonhard Euler. The sequence is named after Eugène Charles Catalan (1814–1894), who discovered the connection to parenthesized expressions. In 1988, it came to light that the Catalan number sequence had been used in China by the Mongolian mathematician Mingantu by 1730.